# forloop.counter doesn't reset at endfor as expected in my django template

Tags: django, templates, loops, for-loop

In index of articles I would like to display first photo for given article. Photos are in another model which has foreign key to model where articles are.

So I select articles from given category which should be displayed, then I select all photos from given category and match their slugs in template and then I (want to) display only the first result.

but the forloop.counter I use for this purpose isn't working as expected. It continues without reseting when it pass the endfor tag.

for example instead of: "1,2,3,endfor,1,2,3,4,5,endfor,1,2,3,4" it counts: "1,2,3,endfor,4,5,6,7,8,endfor,9,10,11,12"

Do I miss something?

here's the template code:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load markup %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
    {% for itm in plays %}
        <h2>{{ itm.name }}</h2>
        <div>{{ itm.desc }}</div>
        <div>
            {% for ftk in photos %}
                {% if ftk.nameofplay.slug == itm.slug %}
                    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                        {% thumbnail ftk.photo "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
                        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
                        {% endthumbnail %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %} {# forloop.counter should reset here and start from 1 again. or not? #}
        </div>
        <div>{{ itm.text|markdown|truncatewords_html:25 }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and from views.py I'm sending some like these:

```
plays = Plays.objects.filter(category__slug__exact = category)
photos = Photos.objects.filter(nameofplay__category__slug__exact = category)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The correct answer is from @rolling-stone; however for future reference - [`forloop.first`](http://https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for) will help with _on the first instance of the loop_ logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop of photos will start over with the next instance in the plays queryset once the loop has gone through all of the photos, however it seems like there may be a much faster way to accomplish this.

Since the Photo model is connected to the Article model via ForeignKey, and assuming the photos are connected to the correct articles, you should be able to do something like this in your template, which should avoid having to check every photo for each article:

```
plays = Plays.objects.filter(category__slug__exact = category)

{% for itm in plays%}
    {% itm.photo_set.all.0 %}
{% endfor %}
```

See the docs on related objects reference for more detail:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Quick&easy. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, it's right approach and it's a lot easier to use _set for following relationship backwards!

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your data of articles and its first photo in your view method through "extra" method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

```
plays = Plays.objects.filter(category__slug__exact=kategorie).extra(
select={
    'first_photo': 'Put this your select query for getting first photo (i.e. photo url)'
},
params={'category': your_param})
```

In template you can get first photo as:

```
{% for item in plays %}
    {{ item.first_photo }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid this. The problem is, I don't have access to the right parameter. At this level/view I have knowledge of parent categories, but cant't specify the article and append the photo to it... Seems quite awkward situation. Because I'm sending object containing all articles to my template, how could I append to it relevant photos to it? But my solution would work if the counter worked...